# Can a function argument be multiply typed?

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm fairly sure the answer is no, but since it would be quite lovely, I'll ask the question anyway.

Example:

```
class Serializable
{
public:

  virtual void serialize() = 0;
};

class Unserializable
{
public:

  virtual void unserialize() = 0;
};

class A : public Serializable
{
public:

  virtual void serialize()
  {
  }
};

class B : public A, public Unserializable
{
public:

  virtual void unserialize()
  {
  }
};
```

Now, is there some way to create a function with one argument that is *both* an instance of Serializable **and** Unserializable such that an object of class B could be passed (without, of course, referencing the derived type B)?  Something like:

```
void readAndWrite(Serializable_Unserializable& object);
```

Comment: No, there isn't, but you can easily pass two parameters and get a more useful function in the bargain.

Comment: Didn't think so, and while I suppose that's true, in my actual use case it could end up being a lot of parameters while conceptually only one object would ever be passed for all of them.

Comment: Thanks much for the speedy comment, though!

Comment: There are a few alternatives, all depending on your use cases. The alternatives include things like templates, function overloading, inheritance trees, or e.g. [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any.html). But if you use Boost, then why not use [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to begin with? And if not the Boost serialization library, then some other library? Getting serialization right is hard, use an existing library if you can.

Comment: Thank you; serialization was just an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template way:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Serializable, T>::value
              && std::is_base_of<Unserializable, T>::value>
void readAndWrite(T& object)
```

Comment: I figured it was impossible, and it kind of is, but this is a great workaround!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, if you can modify `B` (and any other derived type that must inherit both) to derive a single interface that inherits both interfaces, and don't mind virtual inheritance:

```
class Serializable_Unserializable:
    public virtual Serializable,
    public virtual Unserializable
```

Virtual inheritance must also be added to `A` and any other class that inherits either of the two base interfaces and may be inherited by a class that also inherits the combined interface.

```
class A: public virtual Serializable
```

Now, you can change `B` to:

```
class B: public A, public Serializable_Unserializable
```

And it can be passed to your `void readAndWrite(Serializable_Unserializable& object)`.

Without these changes, I don't think you can define a function, that would accept only objects that inherit both of separate interfaces, but allows the type be determined at runtime. If the latter is not a hard requirement, then templates would be an alternative.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it misses one point:  class A and B could also implement other interfaces that may be useful to take as arguments to other functions, which would become pretty complicated to manage.

Comment: @JonVance well, serializable and unserializable are quite tightly coupled interfaces, and combining them might make sense. But for all, unrelated interfaces, this would not scale well. If that's required, then I would use a template, or if runtime polymorphism is needed, use separate arguments, even if the different arguments refer to the same object like molbdnilo suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `dynamic_cast`, if you don't mind the runtime overhead of searching the object's VMT to see if `Unserializable` is supported:

```
void readAndWrite(Serializable& object)
{
    Unserializable *uobject = dynamic_cast<Unserializable*>(&object);
    if (uobject) {
        // supported ...
    } else {
        // not supported ...
    }
}
```